# Analyze Power Amp 2N3055 Wit Multi Diff amp

Tags: power, amplifier, differential

hi guys i have a problem on analyze on this circuit
and i don't know how i resolve these

1- There Is a CE One Stage After Of Diff Amp But I Don't Know Why used This And Why Used Capacitor?

2-After Of Last Stage There are Two Diode Junction On Transistors and 
 (variable resistor 100 ohm) and i don't know why used this on this stage ?

3- On Next Stage That There Is  A Power Amp I Don't know How It's Work?

[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/316300/problems-in-a-power-amplifier-circuit-analysis Why are you asking the same question with different nicknames? Do you think that this will lead a faster response!?

Comment: Use the part designators in your question.  It is clearer to say "I don't understand why D2 and D4 are connected to the base of Q11" than to try to describe their position in the circuit such as "on the the last stage there are two diode junctions on transistor."

Comment: What's with the random capitalization?

Comment: Voting to close because you ask vague questions, too lazy to do own research, double-post same question. If you want help from this site you're very welcome **but follow the rules**.

Comment: Is this homework? Various things hints that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) that CE stage provides the voltage gain for the "servo loop" to force the output voltage to be 21X the input voltage

2) the two diode-connected bipolars (perhaps Q9 and Q10), and 100 ohm pot, implement an adjustable biasing for the output stage; BEWARE these transistors need to be THERMALLY_CLOSE to the output 2N3055

3) output devices are emitter-followers, with bases driven by opposite-polarity bipolars capable of pulling close to the rails

4) overcurrent protection, by shunting base drive [D2/3/4/5]

Beware of the 100 Ohm resistors across base-emitter of 2N3055. These Rs are the only path to remove charge, and or handle Miller_Effect capacitance for the two 2N3055s. Thus high-frequency transient response will suffer.

Comment: Actually, question 2 is about diode-connected Q9 and Q10, which provide AB biasing.